# Finding history of commands in mysql of ubuntu

Tags: command-line, 20.04, mysql

When i press up arrow key on keyboard after logging in mysql by root, i can see what all commands i ran. I want to get the commands which i ran long time ago. So how can i show that all commands in a single file.

Comment: I want to do this because i lost my queries files for lab assignment.  Pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the MySQL history file is `$HOME/.mysql_history`.

You should be able to print it's contents using:

```sh
cat $HOME/.mysql_history
```

If you've run `mysql` using `sudo`, then it shall be:

```sh
sudo -i bash -c "cat \$HOME/.mysql_history"
```

or simply (assuming default `$HOME`):

```sh
sudo cat /root/.mysql_history
```

Comment: thanks for the solution